# Nmap NSE ssh brute forcing password only

Tags: nmap

According to the internet, NMAP scripting for SSH brute forcing would be

```
nmap 172.16.1.102 -p 22 --script ssh-brute --script-args userdb=users.txt,passdb=passwords.txt
```

However, since I'm doing these exercises through https://tryhackme.com, and i already know the username, is there anyway to set the username as an argument and let the script brute force the password only

Also, I've just started this topic a week ago, so do with gentle with the explanations.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from the arguments in your command, insert the username into the users.txt file.

So you create new users.txt file which will contain

```
knownUsername
```

and with that you can call start the same command

```
nmap 172.16.1.102 -p 22 --script ssh-brute --script-args userdb=users.txt,passdb=passwords.txt
```

Comment: Welcome @Martin Bobčík , it will be more effective if you edit your post and provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, I thought my first answer is descriptive enough.